# Implementing a generic vector class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I was working on a template vector class where the size of the vector is not pre-defined. Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class genericVector {
private:
    int size;
    T* arr;
public:
    genericVector(): size(0), arr(0) {}
    ~genericVector() {
        delete[] arr;
    }
    void insert_back(const T& value) {
        arr[size++] = value;
    }
    void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cout << arr[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    genericVector<int> v1;
    int input;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> input;
        v1.insert_back(input);
    }
    v1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

When running in VisualStudio, the program triggers the following breakpoint.

```
Exception thrown: write access violation.

this->arr was 0x1110112.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

What is happening here? If someone can clarify what is going on I'd be grateful.

Comment: `arr` is initialized to `0` or a `NULL` pointer. What were you expecting?

Comment: Further to the point made by @AustinBrunkhorst, `arr` is initialised to `0` and is dereferenced in `void display()` but is **never assigned to**. (I.e. There is no `new[]` call to match the `delete[]` call that occurs in the destructor.)

Comment: Yes totally forgot about that part. Silly mistake..

Comment: As pointed out already, `new[] `is missing. It's good to keep another `capacity` which keeps track of how much the vector can contain. In `insert_back`, it can check if the `size` is exceeding `capacity` and allocate more and move to `a` and then insert the new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `T* arr` declares an array that doesn't point to any memory address i.e. its null.

while you call the `insert_back()` method, it tries to add an element to the end of the array `arr[size++] = value`, which is invalid since your array doesn't have a memory address to store the value of the inserting element.

Your constructor needs to dynamically allocate memory for the array that you are trying to use via `arr = new T[SIZE];` statement.

Lastly, arrays are fixed sized collections that can't be automatically resized, if you need to add element to an array which are filled up completely, you need to dynamically allocate memory for current array size + 1, and change the array pointer to the newly allocated memory after you've copied all the contents from previous array.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.